# Should we apply SSL/TLS connection between service in Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm developing gRPC microservices that running in Kubernetes cluster with insecure connection.

Should we apply SSL/TLS connection between service in Kubernetes?

But anyway, this might be overkill to apply TLS for internal connection in k8s cluster.

Comment: Why? If someone can access your local machine you have far bigger problems than TLS leaks. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

This solely depends on what level of security you want to have. If you decide to use mTLS between services, this is typically implemented using a "service mesh", e.g. [Istio](https://istio.io/).